# Apply style to a separate element outside of a slider

Tags: jquery, css

I have got a pure CSS slider and within it there is a few dot indicators which show what slide I am on. But also I have got another set of numeric indicators which is outside of slider and I want to change their color.

My css example for working indicators:

```
input#img-1:checked ~ .nav-dots label#img-dot-1,
input#img-2:checked ~ .nav-dots label#img-dot-2,
input#img-3:checked ~ .nav-dots label#img-dot-3 {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
```

And this code doesn't work:

```
input#img-1:checked ~ #title label#slide-link-1,
input#img-2:checked ~ #title label#slide-link-2,
input#img-3:checked ~ #title label#slide-link-3 {
    color: red;
}
```

It maybe more than three slides too. Please have a look at my codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZbPvde

Is there any way to achieve it with CSS or please help me to work out how to get it done with jQuery. Many thanks.

Comment: You're duplicating IDs in your code—that have to be fixed. Browsers have no definite behaviors when dealing with multiple ID occurrences.

Comment: Hi @Terry thank you for your advice I am a beginner. Would you please show me on my codepen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are actually using ids instead of classes, so **you can only use #img-dot-1, #img-dot-2, #img-dot-3 once** (same for #slide-link) in your entire html page.
Because of that, **you can access them directly**:

```
#img-dot-1,
#img-dot-2,
#img-dot-3 {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

#slide-link-1,
#slide-link-2,
#slide-link-3 {
    color: red;
}
```

If *color:red* still not working, try with:

```
#slide-link-1,
#slide-link-2,
#slide-link-3 {
    color: red !important;
}
```

This could be caused because of some code attached to inner elements.

Edit: I add following screenshot to show functionallity working better:

[image: Working code in action]

Edit 2:

As you wanted your code changes the current slide number, I did the next to achieve it:

I added next CSS:

```
.red {
    color: red;
}

#img-dot-1,
#img-dot-2,
#img-dot-3 {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
```

Then I added *values* to the checkboxes like this:

```
<input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-2" value="2" />
```

Then I added JQuery and the next script to make it works:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script>
function select(i)
{
    $("#slide-link-1").removeClass("red");
    $("#slide-link-2").removeClass("red");
    $("#slide-link-3").removeClass("red");
    $("#slide-link-"+i).addClass("red");
}
$("input[type='radio']").change(function()
{
    select($(this).val());
});
</script>
```

If you want to make it starts on red, add:

```
$("#slide-link-1").addClass('red')
```

To the script part.

Comment: @burlflip Thank you I tried but it didn't work on my codepen example. Can you please help me?

Comment: It actually works, but the problem I can see is text is wrong-positioned. I will update the anwser with this [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/91JNjhF.png) that may help you better.

Comment: @burlflip I do appreciate your help. So the Idea is to indicate the number of the slide - when input#img-1:checked then number 1 is red.

Comment: Even though my last answer actually solves your question, [here](http://pastebin.com/v2ZVaKFh) you have a working example. I will edit my answer to explain it

Comment: I have got your point! Thank a million for providing a working example.